# Bridged qemu machine cannot receive packets, these are dropped

Tags: virtual-machine, bridge, qemu

I've created virtual machine (ppc) with bridged interface (using bridge helper) on archlinux. Machine can send packet out, but cannot receive anything. I can see packets (dhcp discover,request and/or arp when static IP set) running to host machine with wireshark.

I'm running machine with command:

```
qemu-system-ppc -hda debian_ppc.rawdisk -nographic -net nic -net bridge,br=br0
```

I have also one windows machine running in virtualbox using same bridge and it is works OK.

Cfg of bridge, I'm using br0 for qemu machine, eno1 is psychical

```
$brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.f0921cee9976   no      eno1
                        tap0
winbr       8000.0050b60c205c   no      enp0s20u6
```

Outputs from ebtables:

```
$ ebtables -L
Bridge table: filter

Bridge chain: INPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

Bridge chain: FORWARD, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

Bridge chain: OUTPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

$ ebtables -t broute -L
Bridge table: broute

Bridge chain: BROUTING, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT
```

And last, output of `netstat -i` (where you can see lot of dropped packets on tap0).

```
Kernel Interface table
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
br0       1500    89009      0   1572 0         26228      0      0      0 BMPRU
eno1      1500   110239      0    472 0         37831      0      0      0 BMPRU
enp0s20u  1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
lo       65536    82788      0      0 0         82788      0      0      0 LRU
tap0      1500       92      0      0 0             1      0  54759      0 BMPRU
winbr     1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
```

For complete informations, also output of `brctl showstp br0`:

```
br0
 bridge id      8000.f0921cee9976
 designated root    8000.f0921cee9976
 root port         0            path cost          0
 max age          19.99         bridge max age        19.99
 hello time        1.99         bridge hello time      1.99
 forward delay        14.99         bridge forward delay      14.99
 ageing time         299.99
```

hello timer           0.00         tcn timer          0.00
     topology change timer     0.00         gc timer           1.19
 flags

```
eno1 (1)
 port id        8001            state                forwarding
 designated root    8000.f0921cee9976   path cost          4
 designated bridge  8000.f0921cee9976   message age timer      0.00
 designated port    8001            forward delay timer    0.00
 designated cost       0            hold timer         0.00
 flags          

tap0 (2)
 port id        8002            state               forwarding
 designated root    8000.f0921cee9976   path cost        100
 designated bridge  8000.f0921cee9976   message age timer      0.00
 designated port    8002            forward delay timer    0.00
 designated cost       0            hold timer         0.00
 flags
```

Where can be problem? Few months ago I was using it with success and it worked OK. Thanks very much for your answers!